# Getting text glitch?

Tags: text

anyone have any idea why im getting this text formate glitch getting this china text
"Home 鈫�"

http://news.filmground.host-ed.me/ scroll down!

Comment: Please include your code on this site.

Comment: Thank you for offering help but i get fixed it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Chinese standard encoding set:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">
```

Try setting it to UTF-8

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your first charset declared:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030) says GB18030 is

> a Chinese government standard describing the required language and character support necessary for software in China

Try using UTF-8 instead. You have both declared (look at the top of your `head` element). Try removing the one above or change to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```